# How to check if key value pair overlap exists in jsonb column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, dictionary, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in a Postgres table. It is a simple key value pair dictionary. I want to check the following:

1. it is a subset of a query parameter
2. there is overlap with query parameter

For case 1 I can achieve this easily and it works fine

```
SELECT '{"k1": "v1"}'::jsonb
    <@ '{"k1": "v1", "k2":"v2"}'::jsonb;  -- returns true
```

I am not getting an easy solution for case 2. I tried something like below, but it did not work.

```
SELECT '{"k1": "v1", "k3":"v4"}'::jsonb
    && '{"k1": "v1", "k2":"v2"}'::jsonb;  -- Syntax error.
```

I expect this to return true as there is overlap in terms of certain key value pair.

Comment: What would be your expected result for `SELECT '{"k1": "v1", "k3":"v4"}'::jsonb && '{"k1": "v55", "k2":"v2"}'::jsonb` i.e. must just the key match or both the key and the value?

Comment: it should be true. A match should find both key and corresponding value to be same.

Comment: But in my example data they are not...

Comment: Sorry. I was talking about my example in the original question. In the example that you provided it should return false.

Answer (score 0):

Since the operator `&&` doesn't exist for jsonb, I suggest changing your approach to use `jsonb_path_exists()`, and building multiple WHERE clauses by iterating over the query parameters. For example:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT '{"k1": "v1", "k3":"v4"}'::jsonb AS sample
)

SELECT
  data.sample
FROM
  data
WHERE
  jsonb_path_exists(data.sample, '$.k1[*] ? (@ == "v1")')
  OR jsonb_path_exists(data.sample, '$.k2[*] ? (@ == "v2")')
```